# USB 1/2 hardware failure, but USB 3.x works fine. Can I connect USB 1.1 peripherals over any other pins? (SuperSpeed, HDMI, ...)

Tags: usb, hdmi, hardware-failure, usb-c, usb-2

In previous questions, I have sought for any non-hardware explanation, to no avail. So the situation is this:

My laptop has one USB root hub, with 3x USB 3.1 A ports and 1x USB C (3.1 gen 1) port. All USB ports' D+/D- pins have no activity, including USB C through a hub. However, SuperSpeed devices work fine.

I have a keyboard and sound card that I'd really like to use.

So the question is: **are there any options for connecting USB 1.1/2 devices to a computer over some other connector's pins?** My options are USB C (3.1 gen 1), HDMI, and aux (lol).

---

A couple of ideas I don't love:

- The built-in keyboard, trackpad, and webcam appear under the USB root hub as fullspeed, fullspeed, and highspeed devices, respectively. Are these just regular old USB connections? Could I (theoretically) cut the webcam's cable, solder to a USB connector, and plug in a USB hub?
- I know that USB-over-ethernet is a thing, but that requires a computer at both ends, right? (As opposed to a dedicated USB-to-ethernet dongle.) I have a raspberry pi I could use, but I imagine the latency would be noticeable?

Comment: No; USB over Ethernet requires an adapter. It’s to get over the length restrictions of USB. Wouldn’t be helpful in your case. It also requires a working USB port

Comment: Well, I have an ethernet-to-USB3 adapter which works. So if I pair a USB2-to-ethernet adapter with an Ethernet-to-USB3 adapter: from this article it looks like it would require software but would work? https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/usb-over-ethernet/

Comment: You asked if USB over Ethernet  would solve your problem, and I still maintain it won’t, why are you now talking about your Ethernet USB adapter which is something else entirely

Comment: Because the linked article talks about USB over ethernet via any network connection, including WiFi. (Or my Ethernet USB adapter). I guess this is a quite different form of "USB over ethernet" than the one you're talking about, which, I take it, is a strict 1-to-1 extension of USB via paired adapters.